# charAt(int index) method in String class of java cannot take long input?

Tags: java, string

I have a very long String upto 10^15 characters. I need to see what character is at a particular index but charAt() method takes integer parameter. How can I find character at a particular index (>10^9) ?

Edit: I figured out I can't store String of order 10^15 but I am wondering is there a particular class in java for storing very large strings?

Comment: What you have tried for that?

Comment: You cannot have that long `String`.

Comment: long x=in.readLong();
       char c=curr.charAt(x);

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to store `10^15` characters in memory at once?  What sort of computer do you have?  Can I have one?

Comment: You are actually right when I did the math it seems it will take gbs actually I was solving a competitive programming question may be I need to change my solution completely.

Answer (score 2):

In the `String` class, the characters are stored in an array (`private final char value[]`), and Java arrays are indexed with an `int`.

This explains why the `charAt()` method takes an `int` as a parameter instead of a `long`, and why you won't be able to store any string with more than 2^31 characters anyway.

Comment: So is there any other way to Store very large String just like there is BigInteger for large numbers in java?

Comment: Not directly, but you can allocate as big `java.nio.CharBuffer` and use it to store your chars. The API won't be as friendly as `String`'s though.

Comment: I kinda think that you will run out of memory before hitting the cap of the string size. (2,147,483,647 characters, where the characters is UTF-16...).